500 Internal server error laravel hosting on go daddy
We did the setup. When we access the website the error "500 Internal server error!" pops up. Checking laravel.log the error shows
"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'softkxnz_ecommerce'@'localhost' (using password: YES)".

Note that the user softkxnz_ecommerce doesn't exist. Checking the .env file:
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database1
DB_USERNAME='myusername'
DB_PASSWORD='mypass'

and all looks ok. Checked many sources on the internet that say to clear cache. When I clear the cache from the go daddy SSH it shows the same error.
Tried to change the files .env and database.php ... checked many solutions. Also tried to clear the cache using php artisan config:clear. Appreciate your support on this.

Check in MySQL if your user "softkxnz_ecommerce" have enough grant access.

I don't know what the .env file is supposed to do, but it doesn't appear to work. You need to find where softkxnz_ecommerce is coming from and start from there.

Possibly you didn't give myusername permission to your database database1
Try checking your user permissions
or if your database1 has that user.

The error indicates that your username is softkxnz_ecommerce.
So in the env change the DB_USERNAME to be softkxnz_ecommerce not myusername
hope it helps.
all the best
